# MS VS 2012. my code is not showing up (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a project and while compiling, my laptop handed up and I have to turn it off manually.

After the restart I found that my code is not showing up. There is no line of code in *program.cs* file.

I am working on that code since a month. And all of it vanished.

Need help. I have the executable file working properly. But i need the code. Is there any way to find that code ?

Comment: Will you use version control system next time?

Comment: There might be some deleted file recovery software which may help you.. Otherwise do your backups next time, or use version control.

Comment: @demonplus ofcourse from now on i'll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to decompile your executable. You will get the source code back, minus the comments. This is possible because assemblies (like your exe) actually contain "Intermediate Language" (IL), and not native machine code/assembler. From the IL it is possible to get a reasonable representation of the original source code. You may need to recreate the csproj file manually, if you do not have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the .exe you must have compiled it, if you compiled it you must have saved it.

Where it is depends on where you saved it.  Easiest thing would be to use the search function in Windows – search for whatever you called your program, or failing that, *.csproj.  Then you can open the csproj file with Visual Studio and you should get most of it back.

Comment: I have that *.csproj file. But when i open it there are no contents in it :(

Comment: Open the file with notepad, what is inside it?  It should provide a list of files that are associated with your project.  You could then search for all of those individually.

Comment: program.cs contains the main code. And its empty now.

Comment: Ok, so you have all the files, but they are empty.  I can only imagine that you've overwritten or deleted the text and then saved.  I would do a search on your whole hard drive for program.cs as you may simply be looking at the wrong file.  In that case, I would suggest you try @ShellShock's suggestion to decompile.